# http caching of js, css and images

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache

During http caching, the js, css and images are all stored in the client browser so that the loading looks faster. When the browser shows the contents in the cache, does the request still go to the server to fetch the same contents in the cache?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the cache is to avoid connecting to the back-end service. :)

The browser cache stores data temporarily, as you said, to speed up the rendering process in the browser.  How long data is cached is determined by the [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) the server sends back with the data, as well as browser-specific rules.

An example of one of those headers is **ETag**, from [Google's explanation of HTTP Caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching):

> Assume that 120 seconds have passed since the initial fetch and the
>   browser has initiated a new request for the same resource. First, the
>   browser checks the local cache and finds the previous response.
>   Unfortunately, the browser can't use the previous response because the
>   response has now expired. At this point, the browser could dispatch a
>   new request and fetch the new full response. However, that’s
>   inefficient because if the resource hasn't changed, then there's no
>   reason to download the same information that's already in cache!
>
> That’s the problem that validation tokens, as specified in the ETag
>   header, are designed to solve. The server generates and returns an
>   arbitrary token, which is typically a hash or some other fingerprint
>   of the contents of the file. The client doesn't need to know how the
>   fingerprint is generated; it only needs to send it to the server on
>   the next request. If the fingerprint is still the same, then the
>   resource hasn't changed and you can skip the download.